# How can I get only one field from Django Serializer?

Tags: django, serialization

Hi I am new to Django and I have a question about serializers. I have a Company Model and a Logo Model that is related to company and I also am using two serializers. The problem is my response comes as an object within an object, but I just want the logo URL.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Logo(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logo = LogoSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

class LogoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Logo
        fields = ['logo']
```

This is my current return object, the problem is it is nesting logo inside another property called logo.

```
"logo": {
    "logo": "www.s3bucket.com/url"
},
```

But I am looking to have something like this.

```
"logo": "www.s3bucket.com/url"
```

Thanks in advance for looking at this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your `Logo` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` by returning the value directly not the JSON itself.
ex.:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logo = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_logo')

    def get_logo(self, obj):
        return LogoSerializer().get('logo', None)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

ref.: [SerializerMethodField optional args](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.0-announcement/#optional-argument-to-serializermethodfield)

Comment: Please *don't*: using a `SerializerMethodField` is one-way, this is actually the opposite of what a serializer wants to achieve...

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll have that in mind when writing. Is using the json method a common way to return json?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't need a subserializer, you can just work with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) for this, which can also be used when creating a new field, in case the `Logo` thus already exists:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logo = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Logo.objects.all(), slug_field='logo'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

> Hi I am new to Django and I have a question about serializers. I have a Company Model and a `Logo` Model that is related to `Company` and I also am using two serializers.

If the `Logo` only contains a field `Logo`, and the `Company` has a one-to-one field to the `Logo` it however does not make much sense to create a separate model. In that case you can store the logo on the `Company` model.

Comment: Yup your right, I was had a user profile which had a logo field as well and I wanted to use one model to control both. But I should just add a logo field to each model. Thanks!